# Rewrite URL for articles using htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've had a look through several other questions to see if I could get this working but have had no success at all at the moment so I'm hoping someone can help.

This is the URL I currently have,

```
/?action=viewArticle&articleId=1
```

Ideally, I'd like to only show the article ID if possible.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/*$ index.php?action=viewArticle&articleId=$1 [L]
```